# replace url params with values of an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object like this:

```
let data = {
    url: "https://test.ir/apps/:type/:id/",
    params: {
        id: "com.farsitel.bazaar",
        type: "xyz",
    },
    query: {
        ref: "direct",
        l: "en",
    },
};
```

I want to replace :type and :id in url with equivalent key to each from params object. what is the best solution in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on *matching* keys from `params` to the value of a *regular expression* from key `url`, followed by an update of that key.

On input: `https://test.ir/apps/:type/:id/`

On output: `https://test.ir/apps/xyz/com.farsitel.bazaar/`

```js
let data = {
    url: "https://test.ir/apps/:type/:id/",
    params: {
        id: "com.farsitel.bazaar",
        type: "xyz",
    },
    query: {
        ref: "direct",
        l: "en",
    },
};

let new_url = data.url.replace(/:(\w+)/g, (match, key) => data.params[key] || match);

data.url = new_url;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks body. that's a good solution. I have always some problems with understanding regex phrases :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

```js
const data = {
   url: "https://test.ir/apps/:type/:id/",
   params: {
      id: "com.farsitel.bazaar",
      type: "xyz",
   },
   query: {
      ref: "direct",
      l: "en",
   },
}

const url = data.url.replace(":type", data.params.type).replace(":id", data.params.id);

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).